# Code generating 6k mySQL queries that certainly can be optimized

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a piece of PHP code that is generating over 6000 queries to mySQL and I have the feeling this could be done a lot better...

```
$q0 = "SELECT id_productFROM products";     
$e0 = mysql_query($q0) or die("Select failed: " . mysql_error());

while($r0 = mysql_fetch_array($e0)){    

    $id_product = $r0['id_product'];

    $q1 = "SELECT * FROM productspeople WHERE id_product = $id_product ";       
    $e1 = mysql_query($q1) or die("Select failed: " . mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($e1) == 0){ $count++; }else{ }

}

echo $count. "<br />";
```

My question is ... Is there a better way of counting "non occurences" of a certaing id field of a table in another table? If so .. how?

Thanks in advance and thanks for understanding this (most probably) noobness of mine.

Comment: As an aside, always escape your variables when writing a query, even if it looks like it should be safe - `WHERE id_product = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id_product) . "'";`

Comment: @John As an aside, always use query parameters instead of `mysql_real_escape_string()`. ;)

Comment: will have to look into both your comments! :)

Comment: Afonso, he means us the query that he answered with, which is optimized to not have to use any PHP variables. For future use, read more on mysql_real_escape_string here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @Afonso Yeah, that comment was for John, primarily. But by any means, look into parameterized queries and use them. It is the best way.

Comment: I always use the mysql_real_escape_string() when inserting strings (that are inputed in forms) into a field of the db ... didn't know I should use it always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
  FROM products
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM productspeople WHERE id_product = products.id_product
       )
```

Oh, and it will help tremendously if there is an index on `productspeople.id_product`.

As a general tip, try to do as much work as possible on the database. In comparison it is ridiculously inefficient to send queries back and forth between PHP and the DB.

Comment: yup ... there's an index there! These queries with SELECTs inside SELECTs seem to take a whole lot of time to be executed ... is that normal ?

Comment: @Afonso No, this is not normal. If there are merely 6000 products, this should return pretty much instantly. Are you really sure about the index? (`productspeople.id_product`, not only `products.id_product`!)

Comment: Well ... I think so! :) Products table has the id_procuct, people table as the id_person and the Productpeople table has the id_productperson ... the other 2 only fields on this table are the id_product, id_person

Comment: @Alfonso *"I think so"*? Just have a look at the table definition. ;) If that query is slow, than I'm pretty sure the index is missing.

Comment: The index was there! I rebooted the mysql server and the query you gave me executed nicely and fast! Thanks for the patience mate!

Comment: @Afonso Wow, such drastic measures should not be necessary to get an index working. But there you go. Glad it worked. :)

Comment: Sometimes you just have to be drastic and cut the bad by the root!

Answer (score 2):

To select all product rows with no matching people:

```
SELECT products.* , COUNT( productpeople.id_product ) AS num 
FROM products
LEFT JOIN people ON products.id_product = productpeople.id_product
GROUP BY productpeople.id_product
HAVING num=0
```